# WAAD Authentication with WebAPI OData service consumed by Excel PowerQuery

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, powerquery

I've created a WebAPI OData 3.0 web service with an OWIN middleware, which is configured for authentication with Windows Azure Active Directory.
The ODataControllers are marked with an `[Authorize]` attribute, and the IAppBuilder is configured as follows:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
            });
```

`ida:Tenant` is my Windows Azure tenancy, and `ida:Audience` is the App ID Uri.

Now I would like to consume this service using Excel PowerQuery, authenticating using an account from the AzureAD. However, when I choose "Organizational account" and try to "Sign in", I get the following error:

> Unable to connect. This credential type is not supported for this resource.

In Fiddler I can see that the request is made with a Bearer header, but it is empty.

I would like to achieve a behavior similar to when querying AzureAD Graph.
For example, if I try to consume [https://graph.windows.net/.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=2013-04-05](https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=2013-04-05), a single sign-on window opens, and in Fiddler I can see that a token is passed.

How can I achieve this behavior? what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the expected flow between PowerQuery and an OData service during authentication:

- When you enter the URI to your service in the builder, click ok, you will get a credential prompt asking for your credentials to access the service.
- Typically, you would choose Organizational Account if Azure Active Directory (AAD) is your Identity Provider.
- When you click sign in, PowerQuery will send a challenge request to your service, which is the empty bearer you are seeing. The reason is, we don't know what's your identity provider or where should we log you in, the request is expecting a 401/403 response with a WWW-Authenticate header that has the authentication endpoint url.
- Here is the expected header format:WWW-Authenticate authorization_uri=”token service uri” quotes are optional. If we don't find that header, you get the error message 'Unable to connect. This credential type is not supported'.
- For example, in your scenario, the token service uri is https://login.windows.net
- When we receive that response, we will get the url from the header and issue a login request, at which point you will see the login page from AAD and you will be able to login using your organizational credentials.
- We will wait for the sign in result, which should be a token, that token will be used to fill in the bearer in the header at anytime you request data from that service.

There are two important things regarding your application object in AAD to make this work:

- The AppIdUris property has to have a wildcard URI that would match with your service URI. When we send the login request we have to include a resource id, the resource is the authority of the service we are connecting to. So if your service url is: myservice.com/myODatafeed.svc, the authority includes the scheme, the host and the port number, myservice.com/ would be the authority. For services that might have different tenants for example: company1.myservice.com, the AppIdUri has to have https://*.myservice.com. Otherwise, just https://myservice.com.
- The second thing (and this on is AAD specific), AAD doesn't support first party client (PowerQuery) to third party service (your service) authentication today. but hopefully soon enough :) Maybe just when you get the rest done :)!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! The WWW-Authenticate header did the trick. Unfortunately, after login I keep getting an 'access_denied' error (AADSTS65005: Thie request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list). Does it have to do with PowerQuery having a unique identifier different than the one defined in the manifest? Is that what you meant by saying that PowerQuery cannot support third-party authentication?

Comment: Can you share the code how you added the wwwAuth header in the response?

Comment: Hadeel is there any progress on enabling third party service auth via AAD?

Comment: It has been enabled in the latest PowerQuery release, all you need is to expose the user_impersonation on your app in AAD and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: This has been enabled in the latest release of PowerQuery. Your app will need to expose the user_imperonation scope, and you are good to go :)!

Comment: Do we need to customize in our web API such that it returns a different WWW-Authenticate header?

In my case the web API is at https://foo.azurewebsites.net/odata/things, protected by AAD.
When I use Power BI or Excel to access the OData feed it says:
The WWW-Authenticate header doesn't contain a valid URI: Header value: 'Bearer realm="foo.azurewebsites.net".